# Is the wave equation a hyperbolic, parabolic, or elliptic PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I am a very beginner of PDEs. I want to study the wave equation in 1D and 2D for numerical methods. One basic question is which type the wave equation is. Elliptic, parabolic, or hyperbolic?

Comment: I think it is hyberbolic. Right?

Comment: Yes, it is hyperbolic. If you think of $\partial/\partial x=X$ and $\partial/\partial t=T$, the equation looks like $(X^2-T^2)u=0$, and this looks like the equation of a hyperbola. (The notion of the symbol of a differential operator makes this rigorous.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, wave equations are hyperbolic. They have the similar form that
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=a^2\Delta u,$$ where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian and $u$ is the displacement of the wave.

Typical examples are acoustic wave, elastic wave, and electromagnetic.

In one dimensional, the equation is written as $$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2}=a^2\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}.$$

The general solution is
$$u(x,t)=u(x-at)$$ or $$u(x,t)=u(x+at).$$

Comment: * grumble * Schroedinger equation is not a wave equation, and it is not hyperbolic.

Comment: @WillieWong You mean to say that "Schroedinger equation is a wave equation", I guess.

Comment: @L.K. no, I meant exactly what I wrote. The post has been edited since my comment, which was directed at the original version of the answer. See the edit history.

Comment: This answer does not explain why it is hyperbolic